# Why divider is not showing in the listview @android:id/list ?

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I have a linear layout that contain the following listview :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#FF0000"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp"
     />
```

and the layout is used by a ListActivity, the issue is that the following line in ListView xml doesn't take effect :

```
     android:divider="#FF0000"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp"
```

and the default divider is set. Do you why this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: i check it and it works for me and red color divider,,,,

Answer (score 5):

its an difference of the dp and px.

use this

```
android:dividerHeight="4px"
```

instead of

```
android:dividerHeight="4dp"
```

and use this also if you want

```
int[] colors = {0, 0xFFFF0000, 0}; // red for the example
myList.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
myList.setDividerHeight(1);
```

you will get it..

Comment: I choose dp to be display density independent but i also give px a try and didn't work.

Comment: see this article you will get some idea
http://danroundhill.com/2009/12/18/working-with-the-android-listview/

Comment: Nice gradient divider. :o)

Answer (score 4):

For me this is working perfectly:

```
 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/listHomeScreen"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:cacheColorHint="#000"
     android:divider="#7F7F7F"
     android:dividerHeight="1dip"
     android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
</ListView>
```

Ensure we are not overriding android:dividerHeight or divider color.

Answer (score 1):

**Its resolved now**. the issue is before i decide to make the list in xml i had this code in my listActivity to add divider which was overriding the xml :

```
int[] colors = { 0xA8A8A8A8, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xA8A8A8A8 };
getListView().setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
getListView().setDividerHeight(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is bug in Android Lollipop 5.0 if you have overridden setEnabled() then this happens.
Check ot this question for more info 
[ListView divider not showing in Android 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876904/listview-divider-not-showing-in-android-5)