# How to add dividers between disabled items in ListView? - Lollipop

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, expandablelistview, android-5.0-lollipop

To add the dividers between disabled items (not clickable) in [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) for Android previous to Lollipop I override adapter's method [areAllItemsEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled()) to return true. But now in Lollipop this method doesn't fix the problem. The dividers are invisible in [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) too.

Is there a way to fix this problem without adding the divider in my item layout?

Comment: This featured is not added in Lollipop library.

Answer (score 2):

We ended up adding two Views of 1dp to fake the divider and checking on version to set Visibility. The problem is worse. We also needed to keep track of if the next row is enabled or not, if it is the last row. A lot of cheese on an already deficient ListView (as compared to UITableView for example).

```
if(isItemAvailable(item) || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.size_row, parent, false);
} else {
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.size_row_with_divider, parent, false);
}
```

Comment: i hope its not too late i found this solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876904/listview-divider-not-showing-in-android-5 hope it helps you.